# Errors in using instanceof operator with an interface?

Tags: java, interface, instanceof

I am trying to learn about `instanceof` operator in java as per the link :- [instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/InstanceofDemo.java)

But when i try to run their following code:-

```
class InstanceofDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Parent obj1 = new Parent();
    Parent obj2 = new Child();

    System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Parent: "
        + (obj1 instanceof Parent));
    System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Child: "
        + (obj1 instanceof Child));
    System.out.println("obj1 instanceof MyInterface: "
        + (obj1 instanceof MyInterface));
    System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Parent: "
        + (obj2 instanceof Parent));
    System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Child: "
        + (obj2 instanceof Child));
    System.out.println("obj2 instanceof MyInterface: "
        + (obj2 instanceof MyInterface));
}
```

}

```
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent implements MyInterface {}
interface MyInterface {}
```

I get the following errors at compile time:

```
./Child.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
class Child extends Parent implements MyInterface{
                                      ^
  symbol: class MyInterface
InstanceOfDemo.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("obj1 instanceOf MyInterface" + (obj1 instanceof MyInterface));
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class MyInterface
  location: class InstanceOfDemo
InstanceOfDemo.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println("obj1 instanceOf MyInterface" + (obj2 instanceof MyInterface ));
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class MyInterface
  location: class InstanceOfDemo
3 errors
```

Below is the directory structure where the src code is placed:-

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ankit ankit 174 Oct 25 15:36 Child.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ankit ankit  31 Oct 25 15:36 Child.java
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ankit ankit 920 Oct 25 15:41 InstanceOfDemo.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ankit ankit 637 Oct 25 15:41 InstanceOfDemo.java
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ankit ankit  25 Oct 25 15:20 MyInterface
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ankit ankit 186 Oct 25 15:36 Parent.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ankit ankit  16 Oct 25 15:18 Parent.java
```

Note: I removed the interface implementation from `Child.java` and `InstanceOfDemo.java` to compile and run the code.

Edit 1:- can i consider that instanceof operator can't be used with Interfaces because the definiton of instanceof operator as per Oracle is as follows:-

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.

Comment: `MyInterface` seems to be defined in a different file, and the name of the file isn't even `MyInterface.java`. Hence the .class file isn't generated(and therefore isn't being found by the compiler)

Comment: Wow, it appears to take pretty precisely 7 minutes to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface should also be in `.java file` so you need to put `MyInterface` in `MyInterface.java`

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ankit ankit  25 Oct 25 15:20 MyInterface<---Rename it as 
                                                         MyInterface.java
```

After this compile again and everything should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Looking file listing in question, your MyInterface is missing .java extension.

`instanceof` can most certainly be used with interfaces.

If you wonder about "or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface" part, it means that `myObj instanceof AnInterface` tests, if myObj is an instance of a class that implements a particular interface, namely AnInterface.

Answer (score 1):

`MyInterface` seems to be defined in a different file, and the name of the file isn't even **MyInterface.java**. Hence the **.class** file isn't generated(and therefore isn't being found by the compiler)

Solution is to rename the file `MyInterface` to `MyInterface.java` and compile it. This will generate a **.class** file, which is loaded by your JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Rename MyInterface to MyInterface.java. Both your directory listing and error messages agree that it was never compiled to a class file.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your file `MyInterface` to `MyInterface.java` then your code will run